# How can I relabel the intervals (change the tick labels) on an x-axis?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have a simple x-y plot that I need to fix up for publication. The x-coordinate of the points goes from 0 to 100000. So Mathematica puts tick marks at 0, 20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, and 100000. Is it possible for Mathematica to replace those numbers with 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, and 1, and let me include the "unit" 10^5 in the x-axis label?

Answer (score 3):

The variable `ct` is a map between actual values and displayed scaled values

```
Clear[ct]
ct = Table[{10^4*i, N[i/10, 2]}, {i, 1, 10}];

Plot[Sin[2 Pi x/10^5], {x, 0, 10^5}, Ticks -> {ct, Automatic}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, AxesLabel -> {Superscript[10, 5], "y"}]
```

> {{10000, 0.1}, {20000, 0.2}, {30000, 0.3}, {40000, 0.4}, {50000, 
>     0.5}, {60000, 0.6}, {70000, 0.7}, {80000, 0.8}, {90000, 
>     0.9}, {100000, 1.}}

[image]

`Frame` version

```
Clear[ct]
ct = Table[{10^4*i, N[i/10, 2]}, {i, 0, 10}];

Plot[Sin[2 Pi x/10^5], {x, 0, 10^5},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ct, None}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Superscript[10, 5], "y"}, Frame -> True,
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: @ClintVanSiclen Does this answer your question?