# Labeling the ticks on the imaginary axis with multiples of i in ComplexListPlot

Tags: plotting, complex, ticks

I would like to have the ticks on the imaginary axis of a `ComplexListPlot` to be labeled with $-2i$,$-i$,$0$,$i$,$2i$ instead of $-2$,$-1$,$0$,$1$,$2$.

I have already tried it with the `Ticks` option like it is suggested [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121797/how-can-i-relabel-the-intervals-change-the-tick-labels-on-an-x-axis), but then I got the error

> A tick position in the value of the `Ticks` option should be a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the *undocumented* function `` Charting`FindTicks[] `` to generate ticks whose tick labels we can alter to be multiples of $i$, like so:

```
g1 = ComplexListPlot[{-2 - 2 I, -1 - I, 0, 1 + I, 2 + 2 I}];

yticks = MapAt[If[NumberQ[#], I #, #] &,
               Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}] @@
               Last[Charting`get2DPlotRange[g1]], {All, 2}];
```

Then,

```
Show[g1, Ticks -> {Automatic, yticks}]
```

[image: list plot with complex ticks]